# How do I apply custom heads in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to help my son add a custom head in Minecraft (PC, Java edition 1.13.2). According to [this site](https://minecraft-heads.com/custom-heads/blocks/101-ice-block) I enter a command into a command block, for example,

```
/give @p minecraft:player_head{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Ice Block\"}"},SkullOwner:{Id:"192dbe7b-1309-4c27-a496-5878d81cd1f8",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYTI2NDQwNzFiNmM3YmJhZTdiNWU0NWQ5ZjgyZjk2ZmZiNWVlOGUxNzdhMjNiODI1YTQ0NjU2MDdmMWM5YyJ9fX0="}]}}} 1
```

My understanding Is that the player’s head should change, but when I do this the command seems to be accepted but nothing changes. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/give` always gives you an *item*, in this case it will give you a player head (i.e. the head will be in your inventory).

If you want to change the look of your character, you'll need to change your skin. Go to [minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net) or use the launcher.